# How to generate a signature and send a valid request in indy-vdr using Python?

Tags: python, rust, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy, hyperledger-aries

I want to send a ledger request in Hyperledger Indy using `indy-vdr` Python. To do that, I think I need to generate a signature.

My attempts to send a `nym_request` in Python without valid signatures result in errors like this:

```
indy_vdr.error.VdrError: Request failed: client request invalid: insufficient number of valid signatures
```

I read the Python demo for `indy-vdr` and they only have a placeholder signature `b"sig"` here: https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-vdr/blob/43aa575b6dab8e2f8a20af489dfc1bfccd7a832c/wrappers/python/demo/test.py#L97

In Rust, it looks like you can sign using `private_key.sign` here:
https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-vdr/blob/43aa575b6dab8e2f8a20af489dfc1bfccd7a832c/libindy_vdr/tests/utils/crypto.rs#L35

What else can I do?
Maybe I need to write my own Python function to call the Rust lib?

Comment: I'm trying indy-shared-rs